# Setting Theme Colors for a Java App in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, colors

I am building a quiz app for a “Build Basic Android Apps with Java” course, I had a problem with Android Studio while setting the theme colors of my app. I was asked to change the color scheme of my app by the course that I was following. Here is the exact instruction I was given:

1. Open up the Resource Manager, and choose the tab labeled, Color. Double click either color accent, color primary, or colorPrimaryDark.
2. colors.xml is a value XML file. Within a  element, this file can store strings, colors, dimensions, and so much more.
   •   Change the value of colorPrimary to #EFD9CA
   •   Change the value of colorPrimaryDark to #C4B2A6
   •   Change the value of colorAccent to #FD4D3F
   The problem is that in my color tab I don’t see any labels like colorAccent, etc. All I see is a list of individual colors like black, purple_200, purple_500… When I open the color.xml file I only see these individual colors and no labels like colorPrimary, etc. Here is what I see on that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Do you have any idea about this difference? How can I set colors as the primary color, accent color, etc? Should I basically delete the values in my colorPrimary and redefine colors with name “colorPrimary” etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colorPrimary,colorPrimaryDark, etc. Are common items on your `themes.xml`.

```
<style name="Theme.PruebaAS" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Asd you can see, in some tags there is a color used, those are the values that are on `colors.xml`

> Should I basically delete the values in my colorPrimary and redefine colors with name “colorPrimary” etc?

No, **E.G** If you change the value from `purple_500`, it will change the `colorPrimary` and every item, view that uses `purple_500`